# Iphone ASIHTTP setDidFinishSelector issue

Tags: iphone, selector

i have the following code:

```
  - (void)imageDownloaded:(ASIHTTPRequest *) request idDisco:(NSNumber *)iddisco
    NSLog(@"%d",[idPlace intValue]); 
  }
```

And

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[item objectForKey:@"image"]];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request setDidFinishSelector:[self performSelector:@selector(imageDownloaded:idDisco:)withObject:request withObject:disco.id_disco]];
```

But the compiler tells me that "passing argument 1 of setDidFinishSelector from incompatible pointe type"

It works fine but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass @selector(someMethod:) there:
And the signature of the method should be

```
- (void)methodName:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
```

Look at this example:

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInTheBackground:(id)sender
{
   if (![self queue]) {
      [self setQueue:[[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease]];
   }

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
   [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
   [[self queue] addOperation:request]; //queue is an NSOperationQueue
}

- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSString *response = [request responseString];
}

- (void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Comment: sorry i edit my question because i need a selector with two arguments

Comment: The signature of the expected method is not configurable(Unless you modify ASIHTTPRequest.m) so you will have to store the id of the image somewhere else.